# Getting rid of the empty plot in plt.subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
new_loans['loan_condition'].head()

0    Good Loan
1     Bad Loan
2    Good Loan
3    Good Loan
4    Good Loan
Name: loan_condition, dtype: object


f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16,8))

colors = ["#3791D7", "#D72626"]
labels ="Good Loans", "Bad Loans"

plt.suptitle('Information on Loan Conditions', fontsize=20)

new_loans["loan_condition"].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.25], autopct='%1.2f%%', ax=ax[0], shadow=True, colors=colors, 
                                            labels=labels, fontsize=12, startangle=70)
```

The above generated these plots:

[image]

How do I get rid of the empty plot on the right?

I tried `plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,8)` but I got this error: `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing`

I also replaced `ax=ax[0]` with `ax` but I got the following error: `numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`

The code still didn't work when I used `Squeeze = False` within `plt.subplots`.

Comment: `f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)` and later `df.plot.pie(..., ax=ax)` should work fine. Can you show the code where you try this solution, instead of the one with two subplots?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It worked!